# How to scan images using camera in Black berry?

Tags: api, blackberry, java-me, qr-code, zxing

I have started  one project in which I want to implement QR code scanning functionality.  Say for example: ZXing in android.  I want to implement for blackberry OS 6 and above. I want to scan live images using camera.  Is it possible?  If yes, then how it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Barcode API. It was released for OS 6.0. Before that, there was ZXing (added in 5.0) but no livescan functionality.

Here you are the how-to:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569

Answer (score 0):

Please check this in your eclips folder

path is

> Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\samples\com\rim\samples\device\barcodescandemo

barcodescandemo demo is QRcode reader 
please check it you can find all things