# How to scan live images using camera in Black berry os6 phones?

Tags: blackberry, camera, qr-code, zxing, blackberry-os6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scan images using camera in Black berry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653369/how-to-scan-images-using-camera-in-black-berry)

I have started one project in which I want to implement QR code scanning functionality. Say for example: ZXing in android. I want to implement for blackberry OS 6 and above. I want to scan live images using camera. Is it possible? If yes, then how it possible?Thanks in advance